# Magic Python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, mime-types

I am newbie in python, and I am working on a project that need to detect the type of the file so I used magic library, However the code is not working and it is raising exception. 
 The test code is:

```
import magic
magic.from_file("./example.db")
```

The Traceback :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    magic.from_file("./example.db")
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\magic.py", line 122, in from_file
    m = _get_magic_type(mime)
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\magic.py", line 111, in _get_magic_type
    i = _instances[mime] = Magic(mime=mime)
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\magic.py", line 60, in \__init__
    magic_load(self.cookie, magic_file)
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\magic.py", line 250, in magic_load
    return _magic_load(cookie, coerce_filename(filename))
- File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\pythonscripto\magic.py", line 181, in errorcheck_negative_one
    raise MagicException(err)
magic.MagicException: None
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you followed the windows dependencies instructions at https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic ?

Comment: @SimonFraser yes, or at least I think so. However, I did used 64 bit dependencies and they said that it is not tested. I'm afraid that this is the source of the problem!

Comment: I've not used it myself, so I'm not sure - I just wanted to make sure the obvious option was covered!

Comment: I am getting the same error - also on 64bit Windows.

Comment: @kyrenia I solved the problem, make sure that your python version is 64 bit, and the dependencies files are also 64 bit

Comment: @kyrenia I added answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem, only make sure that your Python version is 64 bit, as well as dependencies files, you should include the following files in the same folder:

- regex2.dll
- zlib1.dll
- magic (no extension)
- magic.mgc
- libgnurx-0.dll
- magic.py